# How can I install AMD ROCm 5+ on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu

The AMD [installation instructions for ROCm 5.2.1](https://docs.amd.com/bundle/ROCm-Installation-Guide-v5.2.1/page/Overview_of_ROCm_Installation_Methods.html) state that ROCm is only compatible with Ubuntu 20.04

Can I still install and use it on Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, I believe you can**. Doing the following, I a least successfully installed ROCm 5.1.1 on the Ubuntu-based Pop!_OS 22.04. I am now able to run PyTorch computations on my GPU, an AMD RX 6800 XT.

I essentially [followed this comment](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/1713#issuecomment-1193332549), with a bit of extras. See also that comment for reasons for some steps.

Some places below, you must replace `5.1.1` with the version you want.

## amdgpu-install

We going to use a terminal. So open one. Create a directory to work in:

```
mkdir ~/ROCm && cd ~/ROCm
```

Update, then download the `.deb` file for `amdgpu-install`, and install it ([link gotten from AMD](https://docs.amd.com/bundle/ROCm-Installation-Guide-v5.2.1/page/How_to_Install_ROCm.html#_How_to_Install)):

```
sudo apt update
wget https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/22.20.1/ubuntu/focal/amdgpu-install_22.20.50201-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./amdgpu-install_22.20.50201-1_all.deb
```

We now have to edit `amdgpu-install`:

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/amdgpu-install
```

1. Pop!_OS is not listed as supported by `amdgpu-install`, so we add it: Search for `ubuntu`, and add `|pop` to the list (`|` reads "or").
2. Search for `linux-modules-extra` and replace the entire function `debian_build_package_list()` with, on one line,

   ```
    function debian_build_package_list() { echo 'empty function'; }
   ```
3. Save and quit

## Python 3.8

Packages in the next steps require that we have also the older Python 3.8 installed. So:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install --yes python3.8
```

## ROCm Repositories and Package Editing

Next, we add the desired ROCm repository. The link is relative to the ROCm version to be installed, [so look up the base URL here](https://docs.amd.com/bundle/ROCm-Installation-Guide-v5.2.1/page/How_to_Install_ROCm.html#_Selecting_Base_URLs).

```
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] <Release-1 specific rocm baseurl> ubuntu main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list
sudo apt update
```

I used ROCm 5.1.1, so I used specifically

```
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.1.1 ubuntu main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list
```

The download the `.deb` file for the ROCm package:

```
apt download rocm-llvm5.1.1
```

### Edit Package 1/2

We need to edit this package before it will install. So we unpack, unpack and edit (by `<tab>` I mean press `Tab` to autocomplete):

```
 ar x rocm-llvm<tab>
 tar xf control.tar.xz
 gedit control
```

In `control`, edit the `Depends` line to

```
Depends: python3, libc6, libstdc++6|libstdc++8, libstdc++-5-dev|libstdc++-7-dev|libstdc++-10-dev, libgcc-5-dev|libgcc-7-dev|libgcc-10-dev, rocm-core5.1.1
```

I.e., add `|libstdc++-10-dev` and `|libgcc-10-dev` in the appropriate positions.

Then repack:

```
tar c postinst prerm control | xz -c > control.tar.xz
ar rcs rocm-llvm5.1.1_14.0.0.22114.50101-48_amd64.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz
```

Great! Now, we install the possible dependencies we just added, and `rocm-core5.1.1`:

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-10-dev libgcc-10-dev rocm-core5.1.1
```

Now the downloaded package installed for me with

```
sudo dpkg -i rocm-llvm<tab>
```

Super.

### Edit Package 2/2

Now we download, identically edit, and repack another package, `openmp-extras5.1.1`:

```
mkdir openmp && cd openmp
apt download openmp-extras5.1.1
ar x openmp<tab>
tar xf control.tar.xz
gedit control
```

Edit `Depends` line, add `|libstdc++-10-dev` and `|libgcc-10-dev` as before. Save, close, repack, install a dependency, and then the package with:

```
tar c control | xz -c > control.tar.xz
ar rcs openmp-extras5.1.1_13.51.0.50101-48_amd64.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz
sudo apt install rocm-device-libs5.1.1
sudo dpkg -i openmp<tab>
```

I hope that all went smoothly.

## Install ROCm

Install ROCm with the usecases you need. Mine are ROCm and HIP. See `amdgpu-install --help` for options.

```
sudo amdgpu-install --rocmrelease=5.1.1 --usecase=rocm,hip --no-dkms
```

Cool.

Now a final piece of setup: Add your user to the `render` and `video` groups:

```
sudo usermod -a -G render $LOGNAME
sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
```

and reboot.

Once rebooted, check that ROCm is loaded with

```
rocminfo
```

**Hurra!**, I hope, and time for cleaning:

```
rm -rf ~/ROCm
```

## PyTorch Postscript

*Note:* Be sure that the ROCm version you installed is supported by Pytorch. At time of writing, Stable supports ROCm 5.1.1, Nightly supports 5.2. Check the [PyTorch Start Locally page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).

I needed ROCm for PyTorch, installed with

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/rocm5.1.1
```

I then got verification that I could use my GPU for computation by running

```
python3
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.get_device_name(torch.cuda.current_device())
```

Comment: This works great!  (I used version 5.2.1, and installed on Pop!_OS 22.0.4)
in version 5.2.1 the Edit Package 2/2 step was not required, because that package doesn't depend on libstdc++
Could you communicate this fix to the package owner?

Comment: @EricHartford Nice to know! Alas, I'm not affiliated with them, so I am in a worse position than you to communicate it (as I didn't try 5.2.1).

Comment: @Snow : done, changed to just `apt`.

Answer (score 1):

Update: as of ROCm 5.3.0, support for Ubuntu 22.04 has been added.

Installation guide: https://docs.amd.com/bundle/ROCm-Installation-Guide-v5.3

Comment: The link is broken. https://docs.amd.com/en/latest/deploy/linux/quick_start.html ?