# HSA_STATUS_ERROR_OUT_OF_RESOURCES ROCm5.1.1 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, gpu, amdgpu

I installed ROCm v5.1.1 as part of `amdgpuv22.20` on Ubuntu 22.04 using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429376/how-can-i-install-amd-rocm-5-on-ubuntu-22-04) (although I also use `amdgpu` for graphics) but when I ran `/opt/rocm/bin/rocminfo` I got the following error message:

```
ROCk module is loaded
hsa api call failure at: /long_pathname_so_that_rpms_can_package_the_debug_info/src/rocminfo/rocminfo.cc:1140
Call returned HSA_STATUS_ERROR_OUT_OF_RESOURCES: The runtime failed to allocate the necessary resources. This error may also occur when the core runtime library needs to spawn threads or create internal OS-specific events.
```

Running `/opt/rocm/opencl/bin/clinfo` gets the following message, in case that is at all helpful:

```
Number of platforms:                 1
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3423.0)
  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback 


  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:               0
```

And of course, `sudo lshw -c video` returns this:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1600,900
       resources: irq:63 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf00000-fcf3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: How much ram does the computer have? A Google search says this may be a kernel issue. What kernel are you running?

Comment: 32GB DDR4 with 8GB GDDR5 on the card
5.15.0-50-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that `amdgpuv22.40` has been released, `ROCm` installs properly on Ubuntu 22.04 and I no longer get the error message.